# "Received message is too long" when connecting to SFTP server with JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I wanted to download files using FTP from a server. I can do it properly through command-line and want the same thing using Java. This is my code

```
session = jsch.getSession(user, server, 22);
session.setPassword(pass);
session.setTimeout(10000);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
**channel.connect();**
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Problem is when the channel is connecting i.e `channel.connect` and I am getting an error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: 4: Received message is too long: 1619214428
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:242)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:200)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:144)
    at com.cca.processor.FTPProcessor.main(FTPProcessor.java:54)
Caused by: 4: Received message is too long: 1619214428
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:214)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you connect with any other (GUI/command-line) SFTP client?

Comment: Actually i am getting same type of error using WINSCP 'Recieved too large (1619214428 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B'

Answer (score 2):

As you commented yourself, you cannot connect with any SFTP client.

So there's nothing wrong with your JSch/Java code.

---

The error occurs only after an SSH authentication, when an SFTP session is starting.

It's typically caused by some startup shell script printing a message, and thus breaking the SFTP protocol.

The number in the error (1619214428) is then the first four characters in the message interpreted as a 32-bit number.

But in your case it does not really seem to be a readable text (were it, WinSCP would display the readable form too). The number stands for `‭6083405C‬` in hexadecimal notation, what is `<.(@` (where the dot stands for a character outside of ASCII table).

See also WinSCP documentation for the error message:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet

---

Still, it's the server that is broken, not your code. You should contact your server administrator or review startup shell scripts of your account.

---

Though you claim you were able to use FTP from command-line and WinSCP. So maybe you should actually use FTP (or better FTPS), not SFTP. You cannot use JSch for FTP (or FTPS). You can use [Apache Commons `FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the reply. You are absolutely right...i tried FTP from command line or Putty and it worked properly. When i used org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient it gives error that 'Could not parse response code. Server Reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0'. Hence i tried Jsch for SSH and stuck in problem

Comment: I used WINSCP for FTP and i am being able to connect. I guess the issue points towards FTP connectivity.

Comment: So maybe you should actually use FTP (or better FTPS), not SFTP. See my edited answer.